# Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 Continuous File Syncing

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I just want to make sure I've got a full understanding of the Microsoft Sync Framework. I have successfully implemented file syncing between two local folders given the example from the 2.1 sdk (very similar, but updated, to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623.aspx). Everything works great.

Now I'm wondering, to accomplish continuous syncing, meaning we don't just sync once and never sync again, is that out of the scope of the sync framework and supposed to be handled strictly by the consumer of the framework, say with a timer or loop and sleeping? I just want to make sure the Sync Framework doesn't have some sort of watcher that remains idle until it detects a change so I don't implement something already implemented for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to explicitly invoke the sync. there's nothing in the SDK for continuously detecting changes and automatically triggering a sync.